# Making a program that has a periodic table

Tags: python

I AM USING PYCHARM TO RUN THIS AS IT IS A REQUIREMENT FROM OUR PROFESSOR

The Periodic Table of the Elements was developed to organize information about the elements that make up the Universe. Write a python program that lets you enter information about each element in the periodic table.
Make sure you include the following information:
symbol, name, atomic number, row, and column
Provide a menu of options for users to:
See all the information that is stored about any element, by entering that element's symbol.
Choose a property and see that property for each element in the table.

I have the below code

```
class element:
    def __init__(self, sym, name, no, typ, row, col):
        self.symbol = sym
        self.name = name
        self.atomic_number = no
        self.elem_type = typ
        self.row = row
        self.column = col


def viewElement(element, n):
    print("Name: " + element.name)
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        print("Symbol: " + element.symbol)
    if n == 2 or n == 4:
        print("Atomic Number: " + str(element.atomic_number))
    if n == 2 or n == 5:
        print("Type: " + element.elem_type)
    if n == 2 or n == 6:
        print("Row: " + str(element.row))
    if n == 2 or n == 7:
        print("Column: " + str(element.column))

    print("\n")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    elem_dict = {}

    while 1:
        print("\n Main Menu \n")
        print("1. Add an Element")
        print("2. View an Element")
        print("3. View all Element Names")
        print("4. View all Atomic Numbers")
        print("5. View all Types")
        print("6. View all Row Numbers")
        print("7. View all Column Number")
        print("8. Exit")
        choice = int(input("Enter your Choice: "))

        if choice == 1:
            sym = input("Enter the symbol: ")
            name = input("Enter the element name: ")
            atom = int(input("Enter the atomic number: "))
            typ = input("Enter the element type: ")
            row = int(input("Enter the row number: "))
            col = int(input("Enter the column number: "))

            if sym not in elem_dict.keys():
                e1 = element(sym, name, atom, typ, row, col)
                elem_dict[sym] = e1
                print(sym + " added\n")
            else:
                print("Element already present")

        elif choice == 2:
            sym = input("Enter the symbol: ")
            viewElement(elem_dict[sym], 2)


        elif choice == 3:
            for i in elem_dict.keys():
                viewElement(elem_dict[i], 3)

        elif choice == 4:
            for i in elem_dict.keys():
                viewElement(elem_dict[i], 4)

        elif choice == 5:
            for i in elem_dict.keys():
                viewElement(elem_dict[i], 5)

        elif choice == 6:
            for i in elem_dict.keys():
                viewElement(elem_dict[i], 6)

        elif choice == 7:
            for i in elem_dict.keys():
                viewElement(elem_dict[i], 7)

        elif choice == 8:
            print("Exiting")
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong entry, Please re-enter\n")
```

I keep getting the below error when I chose option 1 and get the the last part

Main Menu

1. Add an Element
2. View an Element
3. Viel all Element Names
4. View all Atomic Numbers
5. View all Types
6. View all Row Numbers
7. View all Column Number
8. Exit

Enter your Choice: 1

Enter the symbol: H

Enter the element name: Hydrogen

Enter the atomic number: 1

Enter the element type: Gas

Enter the row number: 1

Enter the column number: 1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/stephanie/Desktop/LEGRANGE_UNIT_SEVEN/Periodic_Table.py", 
line 51, in <module>
    e1 = element(sym, name, atom, typ, row, col)
TypeError: element() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: #Stephanie Le Grange We removed the pycharm tag because your question is not about pycharm usage. Your question is about python, regardless of which IDE you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `init` method to a dunder (`__init__`):

```
def __init__(self, sym, name, no, typ, row, col):
# Notice the double underscore either side of init
```

Otherwise the class will not initialize because your `init` is just a self defined method inside the class.